# How to provide basic authorization like in curl command in web browser or in RestClient

Tags: spring, curl, spring-security, request

I am new to Spring and very new to Spring Oauth2 Security. I have searched a lot about how to request the following link in web browser(In Firefox Rest Client plugin).The following request is **curl** and working perfectly fine in terminal through this command.
I am getting the problem while giving basic authorization. So  **How we can interact with basic authorization** given below as -vu myapp:123456.

curl -X POST **-vu myapp:123456** http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=sunit&username=sunit&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=123456&client_id=myapp"

Comment: Web browser asks automatically for credentials, no?

Comment: My question is about the user that we are providing in -vu or -u . In this case it is "myapp:123456". If this is basic authorization then how we can request it. How we can make a request to such url from Javascript or Android through code.

Answer (score 1):

I used wireshark for capture the request and ended the same request to fb just to connect because I don't have a local server running... you can see that is a post request with the body in encoded URL...

[image: wireshark capture]